# Citation undefined Latex

Tags: bibliographies, citing, apacite

I'm getting a citation undefined error when compiling my document. The `main.tex``document contains (among others) the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{apacite}
...
\begin{document}
...
\include{02-chapter}
...
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{references.bib}
\end{document}
```

Chapter02 includes several references. E.g.: `\citeA{mortimer2015development}`

My references database, called `references.bib` contains the following:

```
@Article{mortimer2015development, 
title={Development and validation of the Self-Gifting Consumer Behaviour scale},
author={Mortimer, Gary and Bougoure, Ursula Sigrid and Fazal-E-Hasan, Syed},
journal={Journal of Consumer Behaviour},
year={2015},
volume={14},
number={3},
pages={165--179},
publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}
```

When I compile my `main.tex file` (`latex > bibtex > latex > latex`) I get the error:

> Citation 'mortimer2015development' undefined. Which gives me a PDF
>   output of ? (?).

I'm working on a Macbook with Texmaker.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Using `...` in the preamble of a document is a bad idea. Anyone that tries to test your file has to remove them. The file `02-chapter` also not available, presumably there's the cite of the journal article?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Very sensible to steer clear of them. I'll delete mine to keep the comments clean. I suggest OP checks the bibtex log file, and spelling. I have no trouble compiling your bibtex entry in a suitable document.